# two page different background image ireport 3.0.0

Tags: ireport

i want to generate two page report with different background image (the image is static btw).

The first one would be use for details and the second one would be just a plain image

Answer (score 0):

Do you want one image to be on page one and the other on page two? If so, in the properties menu for the image, find the `Print When Expression` element and use the `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals()` expression.